# format and display datetime in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML with datetime data:

```
<A>
    <StartDate>2011-11-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2011-11-30T00:00:00</EndDate>
    <IsRecurring>false</IsRecurring>
</A>
```

I need to get in xslt only the dates in the following format:

```
01/11/2011 - 30/11/2011
```

When I do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="A/StartDate/"> - <xsl:value-of select="A/EndDate/">
```

I get this:

```
2011-11-01T00:00:00 - 2011-11-30T00:00:00
```

How can I display it properly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look at XPath string functions: `substring`, `substring-before` and etc.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions

```
<xsl:variable name="dt" select="'2011-11-01T12:13:59'"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                      substring($dt, 9, 2),
                      '/',
                      substring($dt, 6, 2),
                      '/',
                      substring($dt, 1, 4)
                      )"/>
```

Answer (score 15):

EDIT: If you still have to use XSLT **1.x**, you could look at [EXSLT's date:format-date user function](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/format-date/). In that case the pattern is `dd/MM/yyyy`.

If your are using XSLT **2.0**, it is handier to use the `format-dateTime` function.

Here's your example in XSLT 2.0:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(A/StartDate, '[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]')" /> 
- <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(A/EndDate, '[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]')" />
```

Comment: I get an exception: "'format-dateTime()' is an unknown XSLT function."
Maybe I don't use XSLT2.0? How can I check it? How can I change it?

Comment: @Naor you just did. Just use Kirill Polishchuk answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Kirill Polishchuk answer if you were using XSLT 2.0 you can simply do a replace :

```
substring(replace($input, "(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})", "$3/$2/$1"), 0, 11)
```

Where `$input` is the contents of your nodes which contain the dates.